# How to get selected elements index of a gridview?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here, I am creating a dynamic gridview.

```cs
    private void PopulateImages()
            {
                ObservableCollection<Attachment> Images = new ObservableCollection<Attachment>();
                Images.Add(new Attachment { Name = "Image 1", Index = 0 });
                Images.Add(new Attachment { Name = "Image 2", Index = 1 });
                Images.Add(new Attachment { Name = "Image 3", Index = 2 });
                Images.Add(new Attachment { Name = "Image 4", Index = 3 });
                Images.Add(new Attachment { Name = "Image 5", Index = 4 });
                Images.Add(new Attachment { Name = "Image 6", Index = 5 });

                gridLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
                gridLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

                gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(33, GridUnitType.Star) });
                gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(33, GridUnitType.Star) });
                gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(33, GridUnitType.Star) });

                gridLayout.ColumnSpacing = 8;
                gridLayout.RowSpacing = 8;

                var productIndex = 0;
                for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 2; rowIndex++)
                {
                    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 3; columnIndex++)
                    {
                        if (productIndex >= Images.Count)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        var product = Images[productIndex];
                        productIndex += 1;

                        var frame = new Frame
                        {
                            HeightRequest = 95,
                            WidthRequest = 70,
                            CornerRadius = 10,
                            HasShadow = false,
                            BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#CCCCCC")
                        };

                        var image = new Image
                        {
                            Source = "addImage.png",
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                            HeightRequest = 35,
                            WidthRequest = 35
                        };

                        frame.Content = image;

                        TapGestureRecognizer tapped = new TapGestureRecognizer();

                        tapped.Tapped += (s, e) =>
                        {                        
                            TakePhoto();
                        };

                        frame.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapped);

                        gridLayout.Children.Add(frame, columnIndex, rowIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: result]

When user clicks on any frame, it will open the camera and after capturing, the  image will be set to the selected frame.

So how to get the selected frame index of this grid?
Also how to find the image source from this image view?

Is any plugin available to use this type of features for multiple image upload in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 1):

As for me, `ClassId` did a trick.

While creating your `Frame`, call:

```cs
yourframe.ClassId = yourindex;
```

and after that in your `Tap` event get your `View's` ClassId.
Something like that:

```cs
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => 
{
    // получим свойства для ячейки, чтобы понять, какое всплыващее окно вызвать
    var specIndex= Convert.ToInt32(((View) s).ClassId);                    
};
```

Comment: Now I can able to set the images,Thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the Row property and Column property of the Grid selected:

```
tapped.Tapped += (s, e) =>
{
   TakePhoto();
   var row = (int)((BindableObject)s).GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
   var column = (int)((BindableObject)s).GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);
};
```

Comment: its working fine,can you tell me how to get the selected item Childrens?

Comment: On each selection you would get the Grid's row or column. In case you can add an property id to you Attachment class and access while selecting any grid section